# How is Spring Cloud Gateway is different from Zuul-2

Tags: netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-gateway

I want to understand the technical differences between Netflix Zuul2 and Spring Cloud Gateway.

- Spring Cloud Gateway is async so is Zuul2
- Both support Http2
- Both support Route filter (functional routes)
- Both using on Netty